# Is streaming a stringstream a libstdc++ extension?

Tags: c++, stringstream, libstdc++, libc++

Is streaming a `stringstream` a libstdc++ extension? This program compiles with `gcc-4.2`, `gcc-4.7-2 (using -std=c++03)`, and clang 3.2 using `-std=c++11` and `libstdc++` (thanks to Andy Prowl, see comments). It does not compile with `clang 3.2` using `-std=c++11` and `-stdlib=libc++`.

```
#include<iostream>
#include<sstream>
int main() {

  std::stringstream s; s << "b";

  std::cout << "ss: " << s << std::endl;

  return 0;
}
```

By looking at the constructor of ofstream it can take a `std::basic_streambuf<CharT, Traits>*` or a `basic_ostream& st`. A stringstream is a `std::basic_istream`, however both are `std::basic_ios<CharT, Traits>` so I would guess it should work.

The following change makes the code compile under clang:

```
  std::cout << "ss: " << s.str() << std::endl;
```

What is the right way to do it? `cout << s;` or `cout << s.str();` ?

Comment: It seems to compile [here](http://liveworkspace.org/code/3PbYX4$3)

Comment: Thanks, yes! There it compiles with clang but I guess clang is using libstdc++ there.

Comment: @AndyProwl I added your info to the post, thanks!

Answer (score 7, accepted):

No, it's a difference between C++03 and C++11. All streams have a conversion operator that enables code using `if (s)` and `while (s)`. In C++03 this is usually `operator void*()` or something similar.

In C++11 we have explicit operators, where an `explicit operator bool()` works for `if (s)`, but not for `cout << s`.

Comment: This means c++11 breaks working c++03 code using `cout << ss;` ? I.e. is that code that used to work no longer valid?

Comment: @gnzlbg: The code *compiles* under C++03, but doesn't *work* for any sane definition of the word. Specifically, what it prints out will normally be an address, **not** the content of your stringstream.

Comment: @gnzlbg, the code is valid in C++03 but not C++11. It still works in c++11 mode with libstdc++ because the change isn't implemented yet, that's http://gcc.gnu.org/bugzilla/show_bug.cgi?id=56193

Answer (score 4):

Actually that would compile *only* in C++98 and C++03, because all stream classes implicity convert into `void*` due to the presence of `operator void*()` conversion function, thus `s` in `std::cout << s` would convert into `void*` implicitly.

In C++11, however, the code will not compile because C++11 has made the explicit, which can contextually convert into  boolean value, not `void*`, such as in `if` and `while`.

Comment: So it is a bug in libstdc++? It compiles with both clang and gcc using libstdc++.

Comment: @gnzlbg: Only if `libstdc++` is supposed to be C++11 conformant.

Comment: There's something wrong here.  I've verified, and you're right that the converion operator is `explicit`.  But that means that it won't work in an `if` or a `while`; an explicit conversion operator is _only_ used in direct initialization.  (Or is there something else I've missed.)

Comment: @JamesKanze: It *contextually* converts into boolean value, in `if` and `while`. The Standard talks about the difference in terms of `T t(e)` and `T t = e`. The former is contextual conversion (loosely speaking), and the latter is not. So `bool b(s)` will compile fine in C++11, but `bool b = s` will NOT, where `s` is an stream object.

Comment: @Nawaz Yes.  They hid it pretty well.  I couldn't find any mention of
_contextual_ initialization in §8.5, and the wording in §8.5 rather
suggests that direct conversions only occur when there is an explicit
conversion.  The contextual conversion rule seem to be restricted to
`bool` (according to §4), and obey the rules for direct conversions,
despite the fact that they are implicit.

Answer (score 1):

It should compile with all C++ compilers, but it doesn't do what
you might expect.  All streams have an implicit conversion to
something which can be used in a boolean expression: either to
`void*` or `bool`.  And there is a `<<` operator for both of
these types.

When you want to dump one stream into another, the correct way
would be:

```
std::cout << s.rdbuf();
```

(It seems a bit strange to me that this is overloaded as
a formatting insertion operator, since it copies the entire
contents of the `streambuf`, without any formatting, even
ignoring the width.)

Comment: should I prefer rdbuf() to str() in this situation?

Comment: @gnzlbg It seems more natural to me, but I think the preference is personal.

Answer (score -1):

there is not overload for streaming std::stringstream, but you can use

```
std::cout << "ss: " << s.str() << std::endl;
```

Comment: If there is no overload, why does it compile with libstdc++? Is it an extension?

Comment: no its not an extension the conversion operator is implemented differently as pointed out in the other answers.